# useReducer Dispatch called twice

Tags: reactjs, use-reducer

Below is my code, whatever action i dispatch using the below reducer, dispatch is called twice. I have read that reducers must be pure functions and no side effects or api calls to be made from a reducer. Else this behaviour is expected. What am i missing? Is my function impure?

```
const modalInitialState = {
    Id: "",
    Name: "",
    PhoneNumber: "",
    Email: "",
    IsOpen: false,
    Header: null,
    Mode: null,
  };

  const modalActions = {
    ADD: "ADD",
    UPDATE: "UPDATE",

    CANCEL: "CANCEL",
    ON_CHANGE: "ON_CHANGE",

    OPEN_AS_ADD: "OPEN_AS_ADD",
    OPEN_AS_UPDATE: "OPEN_AS_UPDATE",
  };

  const modalReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      
      case modalActions.CANCEL:
        return modalInitialState;
        break;
      case modalActions.ON_CHANGE:
        switch (action.id.toLowerCase()) {
          case "name":
            return { ...state, Name: action.val };
            break;
          case "phonenumber":
            return { ...state, PhoneNumber: action.val };
            break;
          case "email":
            return { ...state, Email: action.val };
            break;
        }
        break;
      case modalActions.OPEN_AS_ADD:
        return { ...state, IsOpen: true, Header: "Add", Mode: "Add" };
        break;
      case modalActions.OPEN_AS_UPDATE:
        return { ...state, IsOpen: true, Header: "Update", Mode: "Update" };
        break;
      case modalActions.CANCEL:
        return { ...state, IsOpen: false };
        break;
      case modalActions.ADD:
        return modalInitialState;
        break;
    case modalActions.UPDATE:
        return modalInitialState;
        break;
      default:
        return state;
        
    }
  };
  const [modalState, modalDispatch] = useReducer(
    modalReducer,
    modalInitialState
  );
  const OnChangeHandler = (event) => {
modalDispatch({
  type: modalActions.ON_CHANGE,
  id: event.target.id,
  val: event.target.value,
});
```

};

Comment: Are your components wrapped in strict mode? If yes, checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72112129/11719314

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useReducer dispatch being called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72068781/usereducer-dispatch-being-called-twice)

Answer (score 3):

You're probably experiencing this because your application is running in `StrictMode`. And in `StrictMode`, during development, reducers are called **twice** to help developers catch certain bugs in their app. So, you aren't dispatching the action twice but React is calling the reducer twice on its own because you're in `StrictMode`.

I've a detailed answer about how strict mode works and behaves, you can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72112129/11719314).

The example below shows how during development (*snippet uses the development build of React*) when in `StrictMode`, reducers run twice.

```js
const countReducer = (count, incrementor) => {
  console.log("Reducer ran");
  return count + incrementor;
};

function App() {
  const [count, incrementCount] = React.useReducer(countReducer, 0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => incrementCount(1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));`  - is the line that renders the react app. It does not use strict mode

Comment: Okay, then there might be something else, share your code in a codesandbox and I might be able to help.

Comment: i don't use strict mode but still dispatch happens twice in my case.

Comment: @NikhilGowda You're sure you aren't using strict mode? If so, ask a separate a question explaining your problem in detail.